# How could I have a singleton view for the new Django Form Wizard?

Tags: django, singleton, wizard

I am working with the new Django Form Wizard tool. It will be released in the next Django 1.4, but you can find it here: https://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard

I would like to have a singleton view class for all the wizard process.

This is my code:

```
class submit(object):
    instance = None 

    def __new__(cls, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance = super(submit, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls.form     = SubmitStoryWizard.as_view([SubmitStoryForm1, SubmitStoryForm2, SubmitStoryForm3, SubmitStoryForm4])
        return cls.instance(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.form(request)
```

The problem is that WizardView inherits from TemplateView so the `as_view` method returns a function. So, in the line:

```
cls.form     = SubmitStoryWizard.as_view([SubmitStoryForm1, SubmitStoryForm2, SubmitStoryForm3, SubmitStoryForm4])
```

It's like I was storing in a class variable a function. So, in the `__call__` method, when I call to self.form function, Python automatically add as the first parameter a reference of the class. **This is what I do not want.**

How could I resolve it? Any ideas?

Sorry for my english :S

Thanks in advance,

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue. I haven't tested, but this modification should work:

from:

```
    cls.form     = SubmitStoryWizard.as_view([SubmitStoryForm1, SubmitStoryForm2, SubmitStoryForm3, SubmitStoryForm4])
```

to:

```
    cls.form     = staticmethod(SubmitStoryWizard.as_view([SubmitStoryForm1, SubmitStoryForm2, SubmitStoryForm3, SubmitStoryForm4]))
```